# Тайтлы на страницах

Tags: html, оптимизация

Вот например есть две страницы, почти с одинаковым контентом, одна продолжения второй.

Если у первой тайтл, например: "Выдающийся гонщик всех времен и народов Ken Block", то как сделать тайтл второй страницы "Страница 2 | Выдающийся гонщик всех времен и народов Ken Block"

Можно сделать один тайтл на эти страницы?

Comment: Где вы сайт создаёте то?? На WordpRess?

Comment: Может я, не понял суть вопроса, у меня вопрос к вам? Что вам мешает так сделать? Ваш сайт написан на php, javascript? Или чисто html?

Comment: нет, просто там будут страницы.

Comment: javascript, node, html. Мне не чего не мешает так сделать, но вроде, кто-то говорил, что на всех страницах должны быть разные тайтлы

Comment: сам создаю сайт, без всяких cms, и таких штук вроде WorldPress

Comment: @Zow - допустим есть обработчика url'a вида:

     /articles/:articleId/:currentPage

Достаем :currentPage, рендерим в шаблоне.

Если-же речь о динамической странице, то, тогда, все еще проще, просто изменяем `window.document.title` под свои нужды

Comment: @AlexWindHope, да я не это имею ввиду) Здесь вопрос относится к оптимизации и поисковым системам. Я хочу спросить, как лучше всего сделать тайтл для разных страниц.
Например 
http://www.vesti.ru/news
http://www.vesti.ru/news?&p=2
у них там один тайтл, а есть кто меняют тайтлы, для каждой странице, хотя, там один практически контент

Comment: даже по типу

http://www.vesti.ru/news

http://www.vesti.ru/news?&p=2

надо делать отдельные тайтлы?

Comment: Я думаю это не большая потеря, использовать как вы написали, по другому называть или перефразировать, может запутать пользователя, так как может подумать, что попал на другую статью

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это оптимизация от поисковых систем, если вы используете html или javascript, как для меня намного удобнее в ручную, для каждой странички делать свой тайтл. Насчет поисков, поиск идет в первую очередь по тайтлам, а после по содержанию =)